# d3.js mixing data between different selections

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've compiled my problem into a minimal working example at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wZnL/6/):

HTML:

```
<div id='test'></div>
```

JS:

```
var data = d3.range(10);
var svg = d3.select('#test').datum('hello').append('svg');
var path = svg.append('g')
  .append('path')
    .data([data])
    .attr('class','line');

alert(svg.select('.line').data());
```

This code alerts `hello`, which is the data tied to the `div` selection, **not** the path selection, which is what I would have expected.

Why am I seeing this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing this behaviour because `.select()` has the side effect of binding the data in your original selection (i.e. `svg`) to the subselection you're making (i.e. `.line`) -- as detailed in the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-select). That is, by running this code, *you're changing the data bound to the selected element*, even though your call to `.data()` has no arguments.

Contrast this with `.selectAll()`, which does *not* have this side effect and will indeed select the elements with the data that you have bound to them previously.

Answer (score 2):

Change your alert to:

```
alert(svg.selectAll('.line').data());
```

There's a subtle but important difference between `select` and `selectAll`, whereby the former applies the parent's data to the `select`'ed child. In fact, it's not apparent here, but by using `select` in that alert statement, you end up wiping out the range data you had previously set on it. See comment in this jsFiddle for to understand the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/5wZnL/7/.

Comment: Just to clarify -- by using `.select()` you're only overwriting the data bound to the first element. All the other `.line` elements will still have the data that was bound to them earlier.